# 403 Forbidden error with Apache2 although all permissions granted

Tags: permissions, apache2, ssl, https

I want to set up a website with the root /home/x/y.
The problem is, that I get a 403 Forbidden error, although
the configuration files are set up correctly, aren't they?
Here are the configs I edited and the permission states of
the website root directory

Input

```
$ nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Output

```
...
<Directory /home/x/y>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
...
```

Input

```
$ nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/x.conf
```

Output

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName x.y.org
    ServerAlias www.x.y.org
    DocumentRoot /home/x/y
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.com_access.log combined

<Directory "/home/x/y">
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.x.y.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =x.y.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Input

```
$ ls -ld x/
```

Output

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jan 25 21:18 x/
```

Input

```
$ ls -ld x/y/
```

Output

```
drwxrwxrwx 3 root www-data 4096 Jan 25 21:44 x/y/
```

**Edit:** Yes, all parent directories of the folder y have the execution permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a config beside `x.conf` called `x-le-ssl.conf` with an old configuration - a configuration pointing to a directory that did not exist anymore. Apache used this file instead and so threw me the 403 error. Just change this config too or re create it by `sudo certbot --apache -m admin@example.com -d example.com -d www.example.com` and it will hopefully work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to add virtual hosts:

> This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
> configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
> See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
> the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
> #hints.

---

Instead create a symlink of your `/etc/apache2/sites-available/x.conf` file to
`/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/x.conf`, then restart apache.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/x.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/x.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

Alternatively, there's the `a2ensite` command that will do this automatically. Create a `.conf` file in `sites-available`, then

```
sudo a2ensite whatever.conf.
```

To disable a site, replace `a2ensite` with `a2dissite`.

Comment: Alternatively, there's the `a2ensite` command that will do this automatically. Create a `.conf` file in `sites-available`, then `sudo a2ensite whatever.conf`. To disable a site, replace `a2ensite` with `a2dissite` 

Comment: @Matigo yes, thanks! edited the answer with your comment.

Comment: Instead of `sudo apache2 restart` it has to be `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: I did what you said, same error :(